# Erro: You must provide at least one recipient email address

Tags: php, phpmailer

Colegas.

Tenho um site onde tem 02 formulários. Um para o tradicional Fale Conosco e o outro para envio de currículo. Estou usando o PHPMailer. No Fale Conosco está funcionando corretamente, porém no outro formulário de envio de currículo, aparece o seguinte erro: **You must provide at least one recipient email address.**

Segue abaixo o código:

```
  include("includes/class.phpmailer.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->From = "email@gmail.com";
        $mail->FromName = "Currículo";
        $mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAttachment($curriculo['tmp_name'],$curriculo['name']);
        $data = date("d/m/Y");
        $hora = date("H:i");
        $mensagemHTML = "mensagem";
  $mail->Subject = "Vaga enviada pelo site";
        $mail->Body = $mensagemHTML;

        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();

       if($mail->Send()){
           $mensagem = 'Seu curriculo foi enviada com sucesso!';
       }else{
           $mensagem = "Erro ao enviar. Se o erro persistir, entre em contato                 conosco!";
       }
```

O diretório está correto, assim como o e-mail. Alguém saberia o porque desse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que o problema é:

```
    /// aqui você adiciona um recipient
    $mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAttachment($curriculo['tmp_name'],$curriculo['name']);
    $data = date("d/m/Y");
    $hora = date("H:i");
    $mensagemHTML = "mensagem";
    $mail->Subject = "Vaga enviada pelo site";
    $mail->Body = $mensagemHTML;

    // aqui você apaga todos <<<<<<<<
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
```

Tenta comentar essa linha acima.

PS: o texto está errado. "Seu currículo foi enviadA com sucesso".

Comment: Bingo Michelle. Era isso mesmo. Sobre o texto, obrigado também. Como copiei do Fale Conosco "Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!", não me atentei a isso ;)

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a mensagem de erro você não está atribuindo nenhum valor na propriedade  $mail->AddAddress(), apesar do código que você postou estar.

Antes de executar o metodo Send() de um var_dump no $mail para ter certeza que você realmente atribuiu um endereço.

```
var_dump($mail);
    if($mail->Send()){
```

Comment: Ola Norivan. É realmente muito estranho, pois estou passando o valor no $mail->AddAddress(). Dei o var_dump. Veja: object(PHPMailer)#1 (53) { ["Priority"]=> int(3) ["CharSet"]=> string(10) "iso-8859-1" ["ContentType"]=> string(9) "text/html" ["Encoding"]=> string(4) "8bit" ["ErrorInfo"]=> string(54) "You must provide at least one recipient email address." ["From"]=> string(25) "email@gmail.com" ["FromName"]=> string(23) "Currículo" ["Sender"]=> string(0) "" ["Subject"]=> string(22) "Vaga enviada pelo site" ["Body"]=> string(466) "

Comment: Cara se você está passando o valor mesmo a classe deve estar considerando email que você está passando como inválido. Tente usando dois endereços válidos e diferentes para o From e o AddAddress

Comment: O endereço é válido. É o meu GMail. O e-mail não está vindo por uma variável ou via Post, mas sim está fixo dentro do $mail->Address(). É isso que estou achando estranho, pois estou usando a mesma estrutura no Fale Conosco e funciona perfeitamente.